# Direct speech or not

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

I have a question regarding the sentence below.

> Before the guards can move to block your path, you hear "Let him
>   speak."

Is this direct speech? And do I need a comma after *hear*? The word *hear* confuses me a bit because it is not a standard dialogue tag like "she said" or "he asked." Help?

PS. Should I have italicized "she said" and "he said" instead of putting quotation marks around them? I know I am supposed to italicize words that are referred to as words. What about phrases?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this direct speech?

Yes.

> Do I need a comma after *hear*?

You might as well leave that for your publisher to figure out, since she'll do it her way no matter how you write it.

> Should I have italicized "she said" and "he said" ... ?

That's a convention a lot of us around here follow. But not all of us—and unlike your publisher we regard you as a grown-up and let you do it your way.

Comment: What if I am the publisher? (theoretically) What should I do? What reference or guide should I use here?

Comment: @SiegfriedZaytsev Do what makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a stream of consciousness effect in certain sections, it can be a nice effect to use the italics-no-comma approach.  Otherwise, I recommend keeping things simple and using the normal dialogue approach (comma, quotation marks, normal font).